# Are thoughts of disbelief a sin?

Tags: belief, evil-thoughts

I will not utter what thoughts I have. But I have a negative wrong statement popping up in my head of disbelief and then I think it's from myself. In my right mind set I don't believe in the thought but when I have the thought it feels like it's from myself. This is making me worried a lot. I don't want to be doomed and goto hell fire forever. I believe in Allah and Prophet Muhammad as the last messenger. I want to know will I be questioned for the negative thoughts of disbelief that pop up in my head ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him)
>   said: “Some of the companions of the Messenger of Allah (peace and
>   blessings of Allah be upon him) came to the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allah be upon him) and said to him, ‘We find in ourselves
>   thoughts that are too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Are you really
>   suffering from that?’ They said, ‘Yes.’ He said, ‘That is a clear sign
>   of faith.’” (Muslim).

Keep in mind that Shaytan only wants to cause distress to the believers, Shaytan attempts to shake the grounds of your faith.

> “(Iblees) said: ‘Because You have sent me astray, surely, I will sit
>   in wait against them (human beings) on Your straight path. Then I will
>   come to them from before them and behind them, from their right and
>   from their left, and You will not find most of them as thankful ones
>   (i.e. they will not be dutiful to You)’” (Quran, Al-Aaraf: 16,17).

Find this as a test for yourself and there are duas to seek refuge from such.

> The Messenger, peace be upon him, said: “The Shaytan may come to any
>   one of you and say, ‘Who created Allah, the Almighty?’ If any one of
>   you experiences this, let him say, ‘ ‘Amantu billahi wa rasulihi ‘[I
>   believed in Allah, the Almighty, and His Messenger, peace be upon
>   him], and that will drive him away.” (Saheeh al-Jami’ 1657)

1. Allaahumma ini a`duhu bika min hamazati ash-shayatin wa a`udhu bika 
   rabbi an yahdurun  (O Allah, I seek refuge in You from the
   whisperings of Satan; my Lord, I  seek refuge in You from their
   presence around me)
2. Bismillahi alladhi la yadurru ma`a ismihi shay'un fi al-ardi wa la
   fi  as-sama'i wa huwa as-sami`u al-`alim

   (In the name of Allah; with His name, nothing whatsoever on earth or    heaven can inflict any harm; He is All-Hearing and All-Knowing).

Just don't let this get into your head, try not to overwhelm yourself. Just repeat dikhr constantly whenever this situation occurs. If it's in salat or anything put your trust in your lord verily Allah loves those who put trust in him.

The more you think about it the power your giving these evil whispers, just shrug it off. The more knowledge you gain the less waswas will bother you.

> Sources:
>
> http://islamiclearningmaterials.com/how-to-overcome-waswaas-part-2/
>
> http://www.islamicity.com/qa/action.lasso.asp?-db=services&-lay=Ask&-op=eq&number=5327&-format=detailpop.shtml&-find

**AND ALLAH KNOWS BEST**

Comment: [Additional reading source #1](http://www.iqrasense.com/satan-and-evil/satan-story-shaitaan-tactics-methods-to-ward-off-influences-whispers.html),                                                                                 [Additonal reading source #2](https://islamqa.info/en/12315)